# Executing all assertions in the same Spock test, even if one of them fails

Tags: testing, groovy, automated-tests, spock

I am trying to verify two different outputs in the context of a single Spock method that runs multiple test cases of the form `when-then-where`. For this reason I use two assertions at the `then` block, as can be seen in the following example:

```
import spock.lang.*

@Unroll
class ExampleSpec extends Specification {

     def "Authentication test with empty credentials"() {
         when:
         def reportedErrorMessage, reportedErrorCode
         (reportedErrorMessage, reportedErrorCode) = userAuthentication(name, password)

         then:
         reportedErrorMessage == expectedErrorMessage
         reportedErrorCode    == expectedErrorCode

         where:
         name | password || expectedErrorMessage | expectedErrorCode
         ' '  | null     || 'Empty credentials!' | 10003
         ' '  | ' '      || 'Empty credentials!' | 10003
     }
}
```

The code is an example where the design requirement is that if `name` and `password` are `' '` or `null`, then I should always expect exactly the same `expectedErrorMessage = 'Empty credentials!'` and `expectedErrorCode = 10003`. If for some reason (presumably because of bugs in the source code) I get `expectedErrorMessage = Empty!` (or anything else other than `'Empty credentials!'`) and `expectedErrorCode = 10001` (or anything else other than `1003`), this would not satisfy the above requirement.

The problem is that if both assertions fail *in the same test*, I get a failing message only for the first assertion (here for `reportedErrorMessage`). Is it possible to get informed for all failed assertions in the same test?

Here is a piece of code that demonstrates the same problem without other external code dependencies. I understand that in this particular case it is not a good practice to bundle two very different tests together, but I think it still demonstrates the problem.

```
import spock.lang.*

@Unroll
class ExampleSpec extends Specification {

    def "minimum of #a and #b is #c and maximum of #a and #b is #d"() {
        expect:
        Math.min(a, b) == c
        Math.max(a, b) == d

        where:
        a | b || c | d
        3 | 7 || 3 | 7
        5 | 4 || 5 | 4  // <--- both c and d fail here
        9 | 9 || 9 | 9
    }
}
```

Comment: In the mongo test you provided it will also be failing sequentially.

Comment: Two comments: 1) Are you able to create a test that demonstrates this problem without any other external code dependencies? 2) Why do you have a double pipe (`||`) in your `where` block? That's not a format I believe is to be used.

Comment: @mnd, see [here](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html#_syntactic_variations). `||` is perfectly valid.

Comment: You want it to run all assertions in a test even if the first one fails?

Comment: @Opal You're right, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Opal, I am not sure what do you mean by "mongo test" in this context. (I am a newbie in testing.)

Comment: @mnd, I have edited my original post to include code without external dependencies.

Comment: @tim_yates, Yes, I would think it would be a useful feature to know if other assertions have failed as well as the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [latest comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529817/verifying-more-than-one-outputs-in-the-same-test-case-using-a-spock-where-bloc/33547637?noredirect=1#comment54992120_33547637) by OP, it looks like a solution different from my previous answer would be helpful. I'm leaving the previous answer in-place, as I feel it still provides useful information related to the question (specifically separating positive and negative tests).

Given that you want to see all failures, and not just have it fail at the first assert that fails, I would suggest concatenating everything together into a boolean AND operation. Not using the `&&` shortcut operator, because it will only run until the first check that does not satisfy the entire operation. I would suggest using the `&`, so that all checks are made, regardless of any previously failing checks.

Given the `max` and `min` example above, I would change the `expect` block to this:

`Math.min(a, b) == c & Math.max(a, b) == d`

When the failure occurs, it gives you the following information:

```
Math.min(a, b) == c & Math.max(a, b) == d
     |   |  |  |  | |      |   |  |  |  |
     4   5  4  |  5 false  5   5  4  |  4
               false                 false
```

This shows you every portion of the failing assert. By contrast, if you used the `&&`, it would only show you the first failure, which would look like this:

```
Math.min(a, b) == c && Math.max(a, b) == d
     |   |  |  |  | |
     4   5  4  |  5 false
               false
```

This could obviously get messy pretty fast if you have more than two checks on a single line - but that is a tradeoff you can make between all failing information on one line, versus having to re-run the test after fixing each individual component.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Using the `&` operator is a good idea, which I had not thought of, thanks! The reporting of the tests does become somewhat messier, but I guess it is still fine, given there does not seem to be another alternative.

Comment: Note: I re-edited my question (including changing its title) to clarify it more and hopefully make it more useful, seeing that you found my earlier comment helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two different things at play here.

1. Having a failing `assert` in your code will throw an error, which will cease execution of the code. This is why you can't have two failing assertions in a single test. Any line of code in an `expect` or `then` block in Spock has an implicit `assert` before it.
2. You are mixing positive and negative unit tests in the same test. I ran into this before myself, and I read/watched something about this and Spock (I believe from the creator, Peter Niederwieser), and learned that these should be separated into different tests. Unfortunately I couldn't find that reference. So basically, you'll need one test for failing use cases, and one test for passing/successful use cases.

Given that information, here is your second example code, with the tests separated out, with the failing scenario in the second test.

```
    @Unroll
    class ExampleSpec extends Specification {

        def "minimum of #a and #b is #c and maximum of #a and #b is #d - successes"() {
            expect:
            Math.min(a, b) == c
            Math.max(a, b) == d

            where:
            a | b || c | d
            3 | 7 || 3 | 7
            9 | 9 || 9 | 9
        }

        def "minimum of #a and #b is #c and maximum of #a and #b is #d - failures"() {
            expect:
            Math.min(a, b) != c
            Math.max(a, b) != d

            where:
            a | b || c | d
            5 | 4 || 5 | 4
        }
    }
```

As far as your comment about the MongoDB test case - I'm not sure what the intent is there, but I'm guessing they are making several assertions that are all passing, rather than validating that something is failing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding your 2nd point: I think I may have been misunderstood. See my re-edited question above. (Btw, my other example with min and max may not quite represent well the problem at hand.) The thing is that I don't know beforehand which cases will fail: for example, what is passed to `reportedErrorMessage` and `reportedErrorCode` could be garbage values (different to the expected ones), which I would like to be informed about. Also, I'm not sure why you included the `assert false` setting in the first method.

Comment: I see your update. For the example you gave with `name`=`''` and `password`=`null`, is there a reason you don't want to set `expectedErrorMessage`=`Empty!` and `expectedErrorCode`=`10001`? Also, I cleaned up my answer to remove the `assert false`, not sure why I had that in there, thanks.

Comment: The code above is just an example where the design requirement is that if `name` and `password` are `' '` or `null`, then I should always expect exactly the same `expectedErrorMessage = 'Empty credentials!'` and `expectedErrorCode = 10003`. If for some reason (presumably because of bugs in the source code) I get `expectedErrorMessage = Empty!` (or anything else other than `'Empty credentials!'`) and `expectedErrorCode = 10001` (or anything else other than `1003`), this would not satisfy the above requirement. I would like to be able to detect all these failing cases.